# Standalone javascript Firebug-like console interpreter

Tags: javascript, firebug

Is there even such thing written in pure JavaScript?
The neat thing about Firebug's console is that it outputs exactly what users want to see.
For example:

```
>>> ["hello"][0]
"hello"

>>> ["hello"].length
1

>>> (1 + 1).toString()
"2"
```

Would it be possible to use that kind of interpretor inside code and ran on websites?
Without access to global scope, of course.

Edit:
I've forgotten to mention that I would prefer a small-ish function(s), rather than an entire library of sorts, perhaps even bare bones of whan Firebug's console offers.

Comment: See [jsconsole](https://github.com/remy/jsconsole) or [firebug-lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).

Comment: There are also some [JavaScript Shells](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Shells).  For your examples, a JS shell would work perfectly, but realize that these shells, unlike jsconsole.com, do *not* run in a browser, so they don't have access to the a DOM.

Comment: @Matt: Ahh, I've been using it wrong, nope, it's absolutely not what I had in mind.

Comment: ... then maybe you can explain what you *do* want, as I'm now confused, and it does everything you asked in the question; http://i.stack.imgur.com/SmYTg.png

Comment: @Matt: I was hoping I would be able to isolate a part of the code and use it to parse user input, feed it to the interpreter, and then output it in the similar fashion as Firebug does it.

Comment: Ah right no, I think you'll have a hard time finding any JavaScript solution which does that.

Comment: psst, hey @matt